# Knockout select list - specify a default value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

When binding data to a select list with objects, how do I go about specifying a default value?

I am trying in the following way:

```
var Country = function(name, population) {
  this.countryName = name;
  this.countryPopulation = population;
};

var viewModel = {
  availableCountries: ko.observableArray([
    new Country("UK", 65000000),
    new Country("USA", 320000000),
    new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
  ]),
  selectedCountry: ko.observable(new Country("USA", 320000000))
};

<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

The idea is that `availableCountries` will contain an array of `Country` objects, and the selected one gets held in the `selectedCountry` observable.

Everything works as expected, except when it comes to pre-selecting a value in the list.

I expect it's not working because they are actually different object references. What is the cleanest and simplest way of getting this to work? I want the USA country to be selected by default.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/85crLcy2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split out the array of choices and then set selectedCountry to the USA choice:

```
var choices = [
    new Country("UK", 65000000),
    new Country("USA", 320000000),
    new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
  ];
var viewModel = {
  availableCountries: ko.observableArray(choices),
  selectedCountry: ko.observable(choices[1])
};
```